# How not to be fixed by one option in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have to make different time options only 9th of Feb which are 10:00- and 15:00-. And other days are 14:00-, 15:00-.
But for example, if I choose 9th of Feb, the first time option will be fixed by the day's option(10:00- and 15:00-). And the second timePicker will be also same as (10:00- and 15:00-).But I want make it the other day's(14:00-, 15:00-). I tried making another `<DateTimeSelection/>` component like `<DateTimeSelection2/>`. But it didn't work. Could you give me some advise?

[image]

- app.js

```
import "./styles.css";
import * as React from "react";
import DateTimeSelection from "./DateTimeSelection";

export default function App() {
  const [desired1, setDesired1] = React.useState({ date: "", time: "" });
  const [desired2, setDesired2] = React.useState({ date: "", time: "" });

  const inputDesiredDt1 = (date) => {
    setDesired1((prev) => ({ ...prev, date }));
  };
  const inputDesiredDt2 = (date) => {
    setDesired2((prev) => ({ ...prev, date }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <DateTimeSelection
          dateAndTime={desired1}
          onSetDate={inputDesiredDt1}
          onSetTime={(val) => setDesired1((prev) => ({ ...prev, time: val }))}
        />
        <DateTimeSelection
          dateAndTime={desired2}
          onSetDate={inputDesiredDt2}
          onSetTime={(val) => setDesired2((prev) => ({ ...prev, time: val }))}
        />
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- DateTimeSelection.tsx

```
import * as React from "react";

const DateTimeSelection = ({ dateAndTime, onSetTime, onSetDate }) => {
  const timeOptions =
    dateAndTime.date !== "2022-02-09"
      ? ["14:00-15:00", "15:00-16:00"]
      : ["10:00 - 12:00", "15:00 - 15:30"];

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="date"
        required
        value={dateAndTime.date}
        onChange={(evt) => onSetDate(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        list="time-list"
        name="time-list-choice"
        value={dateAndTime.time}
        onChange={(evt) => onSetTime(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        <datalist id="time-list">
          {timeOptions.map((opt) => (
            <option value={opt} key={"time" + opt}></option>
          ))}
        </datalist>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default DateTimeSelection;
```

https://codesandbox.io/embed/festive-brahmagupta-sbclu?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Could you provide a runnable example?

Comment: I also only see one `DateTimeSelection` component inside `index.js`, but your issue is about two, is that the whole component? It is also necessary that you provide the part where the state variables (`desired2`, etc) are declared.

Comment: I added the CodeSandbox. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the ids for those two `<DateTimeSelection>` are the same.

To make it work as your expectation, you will need to set a unique `id` for each `DateTimeSelection`. One possible solution is that you pass the id to each component

```
//app.js note the id list1, list2

<div className="App">
  <>
    <DateTimeSelection
      id="list1"
      dateAndTime={desired1}
      onSetDate={inputDesiredDt1}
      onSetTime={(val) => setDesired1((prev) => ({ ...prev, time: val }))}
    />
    <DateTimeSelection
      id="list2"
      dateAndTime={desired2}
      onSetDate={inputDesiredDt2}
      onSetTime={(val) => setDesired2((prev) => ({ ...prev, time: val }))}
    />
  </>
</div>
```

and the selection components like

```
import * as React from "react";

const DateTimeSelection = ({ dateAndTime, onSetTime, onSetDate, id }) => {
  const timeOptions =
    dateAndTime.date !== "2022-02-09"
      ? ["14:00-15:00", "15:00-16:00"]
      : ["10:00 - 12:00", "15:00 - 15:30"];

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="date"
        required
        value={dateAndTime.date}
        onChange={(evt) => onSetDate(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        list={id}
        name="time-list-choice"
        value={dateAndTime.time}
        onChange={(evt) => onSetTime(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        <datalist id={id}>
          {timeOptions.map((opt) => (
            <option value={opt} key={"time" + opt}></option>
          ))}
        </datalist>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default DateTimeSelection;
```

Comment: Hm, yeah, passing an ID is probably a good solution, if not a bit annoying, and in a big project could still lead to duplicate ids.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's not a big project here. So I will pass ID. But I will keep it in my head to use uuid.

Answer (score 1):

Well the way you have it setup now you will have two inputs with the list `time-list`, and **two lists with the same id** `time-list`, which is a no-no. (I guess the browser just uses the last one in the DOM?)

So if you can, I would recommend you use a `select`, which identifies it's option by hierarchy, and not global IDs, for example:

```
const DateTimeSelection = ({ dateAndTime, onSetTime, onSetDate }) => {
  const timeOptions =
    dateAndTime.date !== "2022-02-09"
      ? ["14:00-15:00", "15:00-16:00"]
      : ["10:00 - 12:00", "15:00 - 15:30"];

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="date"
        required
        value={dateAndTime.date}
        onChange={(evt) => onSetDate(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <select onSelect={(evt) => onSetTime(evt.target.value)}>
        {timeOptions.map((opt) => (
          <option value={opt} key={"time" + opt}>{"time" + opt}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </>
  );
};
```

You can technically solve this by using a unique, randomly generated ID for each set up inputs, but that seems... wrong (to me):

```
const DateTimeSelection = ({ dateAndTime, onSetTime, onSetDate }) => {
  const uniqueId = React.useMemo(() => Math.random(), []);

  const timeOptions =
    dateAndTime.date !== "2022-02-09"
      ? ["14:00-15:00", "15:00-16:00"]
      : ["10:00 - 12:00", "15:00 - 15:30"];

  return (
    <>
      <input
        type="date"
        required
        value={dateAndTime.date}
        onChange={(evt) => onSetDate(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        list={uniqueId.toString()}
        name="time-list-choice"
        value={dateAndTime.time}
        onChange={(evt) => onSetTime(evt.target.value)}
      />
      <div>
        <datalist id={uniqueId.toString()}>
          {timeOptions.map((opt) => (
            <option value={opt} key={"time" + opt}></option>
          ))}
        </datalist>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
export default DateTimeSelection;
```

If you go that way I would recommend using the [uuid package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) instead of `Math.random()`.

Other than that there are also several NPM packages that implement "autocompletes" for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and answer. I didn't concern to provide a runnable example. I will do it from now.

Comment: You're welcome, and happy coding :) @user42195